# Does it follow that a+b+c=x+y+z=m+n+p

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

If
$$abc=xyz=mnp$$
 $a^4+b^4+c^4-2a^2b^2-2b^2c^2-2c^2a^2=x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2-2y^2z^2-2z^2x^2=a^4+b^4+c^4-2a^2b^2-2b^2c^2-2c^2a^2=m^4+n^4+p^4-2m^2n^2-2n^2p^2-2p^2m^2$
$$\frac{x}{m}=\frac{n}{b}=\frac{c}{z}$$
Then $a+b+c=x+y+z=m+n+p$?
$a,b,c$ positive and are lenghts of triangles,
$x,y,z$ same, $m,n,p$ same.

I edited it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This is false: Consider $a,b=-1,c,x,y,z=1$.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. Sorry for making this an unclear question.

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$?

Comment: This is the full thing now.

Comment: What do the equations say about triangles? (looks like you're investigating three triangles somehow.)

Comment: The three areas are equal, and also the three circumradii equal, since area = $abc/(4R)$ for any triange of sides $a,b,c.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that
$$
a^4+b^4+c^4-2a^2b^2-2b^2c^2-2c^2a^2=(a + b + c)(a + b - c)(a - b + c)(a - b - c).
$$

Comment: I don't think you need to do that much work. $a,b=-1,c,x,y,z=1$ is a simple counterexample.

Comment: Wuau!!!! How can one note that?

Comment: I echo @MariaMazur's sentiment: That's quite stunning, and I'm quite sure I would _not_ have come up with that unless I had a really long time

Comment: @MariaMazur that is Heron's formula for the area of a triangle, at least it is the integer polynomial part. Something the kids would memorize

Comment: Shourly not in that form! @WillJagy

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Formulation